# Do PDF files have a resolution?

Tags: pdftex, luatex, pdf, resolution

Do PDF files have a resolution?

In other words, is every PDF file associated with a pair of positive integers m and n satisfying that in every concrete visual representation of the file, be it on paper or on a computer screen, each page can, in principle, be divided in a rectilinear grid of m equally sized rows and n equally sized columns, such that every atomic cell of this grid has a single color?

And if the answer to this question is "yes", is it possible to find out programmatically what this resolution is? And is it possible to find out programmatically the color of an arbitrarily specified atomic cell?

Is it possible to specify for the pdftex and luatex compilers the resolution they should use to generate the PDF output of their compilation? What are the default resolutions they use?

Comment: almost all pdf files use scalable fonts so have no resolution other than included bitmap images

Comment: From the reference: "This PDF Imaging Model enables the description of text and graphics in a device-independent and resolution-independent manner".  (Some fonts and embedded graphics can be bitmaps with a resolution)